# Multiply Lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I implement a function that multiplies each element of a list by its corresponding element in another list? For example, given the lists `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6]` returns `[4, 10, 18]`? My code is below:

```
calcArea :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
calcArea length width = length * width
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a classic use case for [`zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith):

```
calcArea = zipWith (*)
```

Or, which may be simpler to understand, but is equivalent:

```
calcArea length width = zipWith (*) length width
```

Answer (score 9):

@ForceBru has already written a perfectly good answer, but I'd like to explore how to write this kind of function on your own.

Firstly, we can write the type signature. You already have that:

```
calcArea :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

So now we can write out four different cases that the two arguments can take:

```
calcArea []     []     = -- TODO: case 1
calcArea (a:as) []     = -- TODO: case 2
calcArea []     (b:bs) = -- TODO: case 3
calcArea (a:as) (b:bs) = -- TODO: case 4
```

The first case is easy:

```
calcArea [] [] = []
```

But the second and third are harder. Here, I will make a decision to 'truncate' the list, so that `calcArea [1,2,3] [] = []`. Besides, this is meant to be used with lists of equal size. You may want to change this if this isn't how the function should behave. (Note that this is how `zipWith` behaves.) Also, since we don't refer to the elements of the list, we can write `_` instead of `(a:as)` and `(b:bs)` like previously.

```
calcArea _ [] = []
calcArea [] _ = []
```

(Note also that these cases overlap with the first, and so we can remove the first case entirely)

Finally, we have case 4. Clearly we want `a * b` within some list, so let's start with that:

```
calcArea (a:as) (b:bs) = (a * b) : --???
```

At this point, we realise that `calcArea as bs` is the product of the first two elements of `as` and `bs`, then `calcArea` of the rest of the list! That is to say, `calcArea [1,2,3] [4,5,6] = (1 * 4) : calcArea [2,3] [5,6]`. So we can recur:

```
calcArea (a:as) (b:bs) = (a * b) : calcArea as bs
```

So, the complete function is:

```
calcArea :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
calcArea [] _ = []
calcArea _ [] = []
calcArea (a:as) (b:bs) = (a * b) : calcArea as bs
```

Note that this is equivalent to `calcArea = zipWith (*)`

I hope this helps you to write more complex functions in Haskell in the future.

Comment: you meant "the product", not "the sum". ---- Btw I like this expository (inductive?) programming sometimes, when we go from `calcArea [1,2,3] [4,5,6] = (1 * 4) : calcArea [2,3] [5,6]` to `calcArea (one:two_three) (four:five_six) = (one * four) : calcArea two_three five_six`.

Answer (score 4):

@ForceBru's answer is the simplest way to do this job. However there might be times with more complicated jobs to do functor and applicative operations on lists when you need "one to one" operation rather than combinatorial. So there's this `Control.Applicative.ZipList` type thought just for this job, and it may come handy.

```
import Control.Applicative

mult121 :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mult121 xs ys = getZipList $ (*) <$> ZipList xs <*> ZipList ys

*Main> mult121 [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
[4,10,18]
```

Comment: As a curiosity, it can also be written pointfreely as ``fmap getZipList . liftA2 (*) `on` ZipList``. Although I think that’s a bit less clear in this case, it’s often worth checking to see if a pointfree solution turns out to be nicer, as it is with `calcArea = zipWith (*)`.